# Can I get user's Mobile Number from Facebook application?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/01/14/platform-updates--new-user-object-fields--edge-remove-event-and-more/) I got the document for user's mobile number, but I am not able to get the mobile number, I requested [this URL](https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=address,mobile_phone&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN) but unable to get user'd mobile number,can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

initially  mobile # privacy is determined by the user, now you can get it as you get the email if it is appeared in user's profile// not "only me" ..etc// it have to be a public,, try to do your work with a public number//

you have to check the developers board on facebook

Comment: Hello Mariam, I checked with public phone numbers, that are displaying on other's facebook walls, but they are not coming , error is coming as incorrect field.( https://graph.facebook.com/me?&access_token=Your_Access_Token  ) from this URL i checked, and I didn't get any Phone number .    Thanks,

Comment: Hello,

mmm, look the exception is about an auth issue,, 

you have to check the following link// they avoid programmers to use mobile #,, 
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/

Answer (score 0):

First of all both the values in your field parameter are not available now with the Graph API. Secondly due to privacy issues the Facebook has removed any access to the phone number of the user and you can get the location and hometown of the user if your application has user_location permission from the user. You could give a read about available user data along with the permissions required for accessing the same [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

Comment: No...not through any present API